# How to show the architecture of a model from tensorflow_hub?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I downloaded a model from "https://tfhub.dev/google/magenta/arbitrary-image-stylization-v1-256/1"
How can I print the architecture of this model? I want to check the networks in this model. How data have been processed by this model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it myself

```
func LoadModel(modelPath string, modelNames []string) *tf.SavedModel {
    model, err := tf.LoadSavedModel(modelPath, modelNames, nil) 
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("LoadSavedModel(): %v", err)
      }

    log.Println("List possible ops in graphs") 
    for _, op := range model.Graph.Operations() {
        //log.Printf("Op name: %v, on device: %v", op.Name(), op.Device())
        log.Printf("Op name: %v", op.Name())
    }
    return model
}
```